# How to create a directory and file in that directory using phonegap file api?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ipad, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap file api to create a directory and create a file in the directory created. The directory is getting created, but the file is not getting created in the directory.

The code I am using is:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    var dataDir = fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data", {create: true});
    var file = dataDir.getFile("lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true});
}
```

The directory data is created but `lockfile.txt` is not getting created.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to call the code in an async manner:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data", {create: true}, gotDir);
}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile("lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true}, gotFile);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
    // Do something with fileEntry here
}
```

Comment: So, does the person who down voted this answer want to explain why it doesn't work for them?

Comment: Can i know where this directory will be stored?

Comment: @SSS The Android code looks defaults to the external storage directory if it exits. If not mounted it defaults to /data/data/{package name}.

Comment: Is it possible to create more than one folder at the same time? I mean, something like fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data/subfolder", {create: true}, gotDir);. Or do I have to create the data first and then the subfolder?

Comment: Directories must be created one by one. Otherwise you won't know which failed and what was actually created or not.

Comment: please help , I copy the code in app.js and add file plugin .But nothing happen while build and run

Comment: cant find the file anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this work?

```
var file = fileSystem.root.getFile("data" + "lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true});
```

Comment: it create file with this name "datalockfile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Download file from the url to your device using phonegap

It is working 3.0 and up to for iOS and android

```
var folderName = 'xyz';
var fileName;

function downloadFile(URL) {
    //step to request a file system 
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

    function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
        fileName = download_link.substr(download_link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //Get filename of URL
        var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
        directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
        var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
        var fp = fileSystem.root.toNativeURL(); // Returns Fullpath of local directory

        fp = fp + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
        // download function call
        filetransfer(download_link, fp);
    }

    function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
        // Directory created successfuly
    }

    function onDirectoryFail(error) {
        //Error while creating directory
        alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);

    }

    function fileSystemFail(evt) {
        //Unable to access file system
        alert(evt.target.error.code);
    }
}

function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    // File download function with URL and local path
    fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
        function(entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            //Download abort errors or download failed errors
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function download(URL, fileName){
   var folderName = 'xyz';
   var uri = encodeURI(URL);

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function (fileSystem) {
                var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
                directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); 
                var filename = fileSystem.root.toURL() + folderName + "/" + uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                fileTransfer.download(uri, filename,
                    function(entry) { // download success
                        var path = entry.toURL(); //**THIS IS WHAT I NEED**
                        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Download Completed: " + entry.fullPath, function (a) {
                        }, function (b) {
                        });
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log("error")
                    } // irrelevant download error
                );`enter code here`
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("error2")
            } // irrelevant request fileSystem error
        );

        function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
            // Directory created successfuly
            console.log("Directory created successfuly: " + JSON.stringify(parent));
            var fp = (parent.nativeURL) + fileName;
            filetransfer(download_link, fp);
        }

        function onDirectoryFail(error) {
            //Error while creating directory
            alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This download code work for ios and android both with latest version of cordova 3.4+ all. as well as ionic framework